# Make jar with intellij idea in a maven project with wrong MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I make a maven project with intellij idea.but when i build the project to jar ,the  MANIFEST.MF in jar is not mine , looks like my maven lib`s MANIFEST.MF

my MANIFEST.MF in intellij idea:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJeEN.png)

MANIFEST.MF in jar :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah4ZU.png)

Comment: How did you add your manifest to the pom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Maven Archiver generates the manifest file for you. You can specify a custom manifest file with the `<manifestFile>` configuration element of the archiver, for example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifestFile>src/main/manifests/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
```

More info regarding the archiver can be found here [Maven Archiver](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html)